# VAST: Unable to request ads from server. Cause: Error #2048

Tags: xml, vast

I am getting error in testing VAST using passing URL of XML file but if i am trying to pass XML code than it's working fine.

**VAST Testing Site:**

https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/vastinspector

http://demo.jwplayer.com/ad-tester/

**VAST Tag Content**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VAST version="2.0">
    <Ad id="Adotube">
        <InLine>
            <AdSystem version="3.0">Webtech91</AdSystem>
            <AdTitle>My First Testing VAST</AdTitle>
            <Description>N/A Description</Description>
            <Impression>
                <![CDATA[http://example.com/p1.php?caller=impression]]>
            </Impression>
            <Creatives>
                <Creative sequence="1" id="oRYYzvQ">
                    <Linear>
                        <Duration>00:00:13</Duration>
                        <TrackingEvents>
                            <Tracking event="firstQuartile">
                                <![CDATA[http://stats.adotube.com/log_stats.php?urid=47700438a615ba109836d0afe562f2a7&action=Views25&b=0&billing_type=0&avpid_stats=oRYYzvQ&pid=&gid=&publisher_id=1797&capid=&wid=wid_2079189957_53d35a1e808224.02092038&geo=IN_09_Rajkot___&ad_id=test&cat_id=0&cam_id=7913&cb=53d35a1e906781.01456052&value=&test=NA_NA_NA_NA_NA_NA_NA_NA&bk=&adex_id=&HTTP_REFERER=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.longtailvideo.com&video_identifier=longtailvideo.com%2Ctest&urid=47700438a615ba109836d0afe562f2a7]]>
                            </Tracking>
                            <Tracking event="midpoint">
                                <![CDATA[http://stats.adotube.com/log_stats.php?urid=47700438a615ba109836d0afe562f2a7&action=Views50&b=0&billing_type=0&avpid_stats=oRYYzvQ&pid=&gid=&publisher_id=1797&capid=&wid=wid_2079189957_53d35a1e808224.02092038&geo=IN_09_Rajkot___&ad_id=test&cat_id=0&cam_id=7913&cb=53d35a1e906781.01456052&value=&test=NA_NA_NA_NA_NA_NA_NA_NA&bk=&adex_id=&HTTP_REFERER=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.longtailvideo.com&video_identifier=longtailvideo.com%2Ctest&urid=47700438a615ba109836d0afe562f2a7]]>
                            </Tracking>
                            <Tracking event="thirdQuartile">
                                <![CDATA[http://stats.adotube.com/log_stats.php?urid=47700438a615ba109836d0afe562f2a7&action=Views75&b=0&billing_type=0&avpid_stats=oRYYzvQ&pid=&gid=&publisher_id=1797&capid=&wid=wid_2079189957_53d35a1e808224.02092038&geo=IN_09_Rajkot___&ad_id=test&cat_id=0&cam_id=7913&cb=53d35a1e906781.01456052&value=&test=NA_NA_NA_NA_NA_NA_NA_NA&bk=&adex_id=&HTTP_REFERER=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.longtailvideo.com&video_identifier=longtailvideo.com%2Ctest&urid=47700438a615ba109836d0afe562f2a7]]>
                            </Tracking>
                            <Tracking event="complete">
                                <![CDATA[http://stats.adotube.com/log_stats.php?urid=47700438a615ba109836d0afe562f2a7&action=Views100&b=0&billing_type=0&avpid_stats=oRYYzvQ&pid=&gid=&publisher_id=1797&capid=&wid=wid_2079189957_53d35a1e808224.02092038&geo=IN_09_Rajkot___&ad_id=test&cat_id=0&cam_id=7913&cb=53d35a1e906781.01456052&value=&test=NA_NA_NA_NA_NA_NA_NA_NA&bk=&adex_id=&HTTP_REFERER=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.longtailvideo.com&video_identifier=longtailvideo.com%2Ctest&urid=47700438a615ba109836d0afe562f2a7]]>
                            </Tracking>
                        </TrackingEvents>
                        <VideoClicks>
                            <ClickThrough>
                            </ClickThrough>
                        </VideoClicks>
                        <MediaFiles>
                            <MediaFile delivery="progressive" bitrate="600" width="640" height="360" type="video/mp4">
                                <![CDATA[http://creative.js.adotube.com/creatives/dev_test/pre1_video1_html5.mp4]]>
                            </MediaFile>
                            <MediaFile delivery="progressive" bitrate="600" width="640" height="360" type="video/x-flv">
                                <![CDATA[http://creative.js.adotube.com/creatives/dev_test/pre1_video1_html5.flv]]>
                            </MediaFile>
                            <MediaFile delivery="progressive" bitrate="600" width="640" height="360" type="video/webm">
                                <![CDATA[http://creative.js.adotube.com/creatives/dev_test/pre1_video1_html5.webm]]>
                            </MediaFile>
                        </MediaFiles>
                    </Linear>
                </Creative>
            </Creatives>
        </InLine>
    </Ad>
</VAST>
```

I found somewhere that may be it's an cross browser issue so i put following code but still not working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain="*"/></cross-domain-policy>
<VAST version="2.0">
```

**URL sample:**

http://www.examplesite.com/p1.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. This is cross domain issue. And the following string:
`<cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain="*"/></cross-domain-policy>` should be in the crossdomain.xml file, which should be present in the root of server, where you placed your VAST. It is required by flash security policy.

So, you should put crossdomain.xml in the root of your server, or update it with the string above.